# gsutil failing on worker_thread.start()

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have been using gsutil for the past 3 months.

I noticed an error that occurs randomly from time to time, e.g. sometimes once a week, sometimes once every two weeks and so on.

From the log the error looks like it fails to start a new thread for executing the gsutil command:

```
Process SyncManager-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
Process SyncManager-ProTraceback (most rTraceback (most re  File "/usr/lib6  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.Process Process-34:
Traceback (most recent call  File "  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process  File "/usr/lib64/python2    t.start()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.py", line 474, in start
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/share/gsutil/gslib/command.py", line 1444, in _ApplyThreads
    gsutil_api_map=sCopying gs://*****  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _boots    worker_thread.start()
 "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/share/gsutil/gslib/command.py", line 1444, in _ApplyThreads
```

I haven't managed to find any official support of Google's gsutil other than posting a question here.

Has anyone seen this before or know why it's happenning? Appreciate for your time.

Thanks,

Comment: Is that the full exception? It looks like the last line got cut off, which has the actual error name.